# Where can I find latest (beta/ctp maybe) version of Prism and/or any quickstart for composite WPF applications with Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, prism

All I've found about composite applications is for VS 2008. How do I start with composite WPF applications with VS 2010?

Can you recommend a good intro for creating a composite WPF application from scratch with Visual Studio 2010?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The VS2010 build with the latest bits for Prism (and entlib and unity, etc) can be found here on codeplex:

http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/changes/42969

The RI (reference implementation) works with the latest bits, but they haven't sorted the quickstarts yet.

I found this blog series helpful when I first started out with MVVM and Prism:

http://www.developmentalmadness.com/archive/2009/10/03/mvvm-with-prism-101-ndash-part-1-the-bootstrapper.aspx

Have fun! :)

Answer (score 2):

[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/dphill/prism-template-pack-for-visual-studio-2010)

Preview:

[image]
<sub>(source: [msdn.com](https://web.archive.org/web/20140429171224/http://blogs.msdn.com/blogfiles/dphill/WindowsLiveWriter/PrismTemplatePackforVisualStudio2010_A42A/NewProject_thumb.png))</sub>

​